# ios NSURLConnection how to post back a html form without creating a new request with headers and post values

Tags: ios, forms, postback, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I am making a request to a html webpage using NSURLConnection. The page returns a web form with many (changing) hidden fields.

There is an ok/cancel button in the form with associated actions on the server.

My question is , how can I request the form and then perform a post back to the server simulating press of "OK" button without picking apart the webform and recreating a new NSURLConnection request

Psudo code of what I would like to do:

```
NSURLConnection *requestForm = [NSURLConnection NSURLConnectionWithString:@"http://mywebform.com"];

[requestForm doTheRequestAndGetTheWebPageBackWithFormThatIsInsideOfIt];

[requestFrom DoThePostBackSimulatingUserPressedOKButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UIWebView to load the page，and call "stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:" to simulate button clicking.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Could you give me an example please of what the string part is? Even something like the "Add Comment" button next to this comment box - how would I simulate pressing that?

Comment: How could I simulate this ok button <form method="post" action="/a/action1/?_mn_=10&amp;refid=13">
  <input type="hidden" name="xxx" value="aasdf" autocomplete="off" />
  <input type="hidden" name="asfasdf" value="€,´,€,´,水,Д,Є" />
  <input type="hidden" name="asdsdfsff" value="asdfsdfsdfsdsfd" />
  <input value="Confirm" type="submit" name="confirm_this_action" class="btn btnC" /> 
  <a href="/asdfsadfdsff.php?asdfsdf=sadfsadfdfsadfsas&amp;sdfsfd=asdfsadffdsafds&amp;_mn_=5&amp;refid=13" data-sigil="cancel-link">Cancel</a>
 </form>

Comment: document.getElementById('your_button_id').click();

Comment: in this example is this confirm_this_action

Comment: OK, like this "document.getElementsByName('confirm_this_action')[0]"

Comment: Not working :(
NSString *res = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByName('confirm_this_action')[0].click();"];